# GIT file version history matching with local

Tags: git

I have one file from Git history in local folder.  say 2 months back and post that there are 10-15 commits to this file.  Is it possible to find which version (commit) is matching with my local file via any toold or scripts?

Comment: I'm not sure the details of how to get it easily, but if you check the HEAD on that local folder, that should point to the commit that you can reference in the updated repo?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `git diff` to compare your local file against the revisions from 15 commits ago to the present:

```
git diff master~15:somefile.txt somefile.txt
git diff master~14:somefile.txt somefile.txt
...
git diff master~1:somefile.txt somefile.txt
```

When (and if) you see an empty diff, then you have your match.  Keep in mind that more than one commit may actually match if, for example, `somefile.txt` did not change across several commits.

It is probably also possible to write a more complex script which will loop over versions of the file.